# How to use JQuery in Nuxt.js

Tags: jquery, vue.js, nuxt.js

i want to use JQuery in function computed() in my component:

```
computed: {
    bgStyle() {
        var $bg_wr = $('.bg-wr'),
    }
}
```

For this in nuxt.config.js i tried to connect JQuery:

```
head: {
   script: [
      { src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js' },
    ]
}
```

But it doesn't work. I get error '$ is not defined'.
What i do wrong?

Comment: No worries.  Also it's generally not necessary / helpful / good to use jQuery with Vue/Nuxt unless it's absolutely necessary.  For example, if you need to use some existing library

Comment: @shob yes i agree with you, but i use slider :(

Comment: You have a lot of sliders in the non-jquery environment tbh. Here are a few: https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#slider Those are standalone, I will not even talk about the CSS frameworks that have some backed into them like Boostrap, Buefy, Vuetify and so on... Drop jQuery and use some JS/Vue ones. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated above, you should not use jQuery with Vue/Nuxt because it defeats the whole purpose of having a declarative framework vs using an imperative library (jQuery).

The ecosystem is even bigger without jQuery, and much more maintained/flexible.

If you **really** want to use jQuery, you could probably follow this kind of tutorial: https://kaloraat.com/articles/how-to-use-jquery-in-nuxtjs
Then, use your function into a `method`, but I recommend not to.

Answer (score 1):

in Nuxt3

First you need to install jquery in your project

```
npm i jquery
```

Then in the file `~/plugins/jquery.js` add the following codes:

```
import $ from 'jquery'
window.jQuery = window.$ = $
export default jQuery;
```

And finally add the following code to the `nuxt.config.ts`

```
plugins: [
  { src: "~/plugins/jquery", mode: "client" },
],
```

Sample

```
<script setup>
onMounted(()=>{
  console.log($('body'));
})
</script>
```