# Nuxt 3: How to use external libraries that require jQuery?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, slickgrid

I have a vue/vite website that i'm migrating to Nuxt to improve structure and SEO.

Most pages work fine, but the page that uses jQuery returns a 500 Error, jquery is not defined.

I thought this must be because it's trying to render server-side so I disabled that (so I thought) by adding the following code in nuxt.config.ts:

```
routeRules: {
    '/profile/**': { ssr: false },
    '/team/**': { ssr: false },
}
```

But I still get the following error.

```
500
jQuery is not defined

at http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/assets/slickgrid/lib/jquery-ui-1.11.3.min.js:6:75
at http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/assets/slickgrid/lib/jquery-ui-1.11.3.min.js:6:84
```

This is the start of the vue file that is causing the error:

```
<script>
import {$,jQuery} from 'jquery'
// export for others scripts to use
// window.$ = $;
// window.jQuery = jQuery;
// import '@/assets/jquery.js'
import '@/assets/slickgrid/lib/firebugx.js'
import '@/assets/slickgrid/lib/jquery-ui-1.11.3.min.js'
```

How can I load these files client-side only? Apologies if this is a dumb question, I might be completely misunderstanding the concept.

Comment: please note that the latest version of [6pac/SlickGrid](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid) no longer requires jQuery/jQueryUI. It's all browser native code now and the only dependency left is `SortableJS` that replaces jQueryUI for reordering columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated here, it's not recommended to use jquery on your Nuxt projects.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66423820/21341655

If you really want to, there are some ways to do it.

`npm i jquery`

**Method 1**

`~/plugins/jquery.client.js`

```js
import $ from 'jquery'
export default defineNuxtPlugin( () => {
    window.jQuery = window.$ = $
} )
```

**Method 2**

`~/plugins/jquery.js`

```js
import $ from 'jquery'
export default defineNuxtPlugin( ( nuxtAPp ) => {
   nuxtAPp.hook( 'app:beforeMount', () => {
      window.jQuery = window.$ = $
   } )
} )
```

**Method 3**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76454524/21341655

Example usage

```js
<script setup>
onMounted(() => {
    $('#hello').append('World')
})
</script>
<template>
    <div>
        <div id="hello"></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

To use JQuery in a single page, here is the basic example.

`~/pages/test.vue`

```js
<script setup>
import $ from 'jquery'

onMounted(() => {
    window.jQuery = window.$ = $
    $('.hello').append('Hello jQuery')
})

</script>
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="hello"></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Tested and it works.

[image]

Hope that helps!

Edit: Disabling the SSR in `nuxt.config.ts` is optional. These methods will work without applying the `routeRules`

**Slick Grid basic configuration and example**

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>SlickGrid Example</h1>
    <div class="slick-grid-container" ref="slickGridContainer"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
  useHead({
    script: [
      {
        src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/6pac-slickgrid/4.0.1/slick.core.min.js',
        type: 'text/javascript'
      },
      {
        src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/6pac-slickgrid/4.0.1/slick.compositeeditor.min.js',
        type: 'text/javascript'
      },
      {
        src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/6pac-slickgrid/4.0.1/slick.grid.min.js',
        type: 'text/javascript'
      },
      {
        src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/6pac-slickgrid/4.0.1/slick.interactions.min.js',
        type: 'text/javascript'
      }
    ],
    link: [
      {
        href: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/6pac-slickgrid/4.0.1/slick.grid.min.css',
        rel: 'stylesheet'
      },
      {
        href: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/6pac-slickgrid/4.0.1/slick-default-theme.min.css',
        rel: 'stylesheet'
      }
    ]
  })

  const slickGridContainer = ref(null)

  let grid

  const columns = [
    { id: 'id', name: 'ID', field: 'id' },
    { id: 'name', name: 'Name', field: 'name' }
    // Define more columns
  ]

  const options = {
    enableCellNavigation: true,
    enableColumnReorder: false
    // Define more options
  }

  const data = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Item 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Item 2' }
    // Add more data
  ]

  onMounted(() => {
    grid = new Slick.Grid(slickGridContainer.value, data, columns, options)
  })

  onBeforeUnmount(() => {
    grid.destroy()
  })
</script>

<style scoped>
  .slick-grid-container {
    height: 300px;
  }
</style>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I never thought that jQuery could be the issue. I've tried each of the methods and they let me use jQuery in the OnMounted section. But as soon as I try to import jquery-ui or slickgrid, it fails with the same error. To fix this,I tried using Methods 1 and 2, but moving the rest of the import lines within this file as well, but this fails with the same error. What is the correct way to import further js files that depend on jQuery?

Comment: I've edited my answer. I haven't use slickGrid before but this configuration should work as it is tested with the basic configuration and it works.

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks, the useHead function avoids loading the scripts in all pages.  I worked out that you can use scripts from the public folder like this: src: `/slickgrid-spreadsheet-plugins-master/ext.headerfilter.js`,